# C Programming Temperature Conversion

Tags: c

I'm a beginner and would like to know why the code below doesn't work? My compiler is Apple Xcode.

Issue 1 : 'conio.h' file not found
Issue 2 : Type specifier missing, default to 'int'.
Issue 3 : Implicit declaration of function 'getch' is invalid in C99

Would someone explain to me what the above mean? I'm clueless...

---

Here below is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> //----- ISSUE 1 -----//

main() { //----- ISSUE 2 -----//

  float a, b, centigrade, fahrenheit;
  int x; 

  printf("Press 1:Fahrenheit To Centigrade\nPress 2:Centigrade to  Fahrenheit\n");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  switch(x)
    {
      case 1:
      printf("\nEnter the value of Fahrenheit Temperature:");
      scanf("%f",&a);
      centigrade=5*(a-32)/9;
        printf("Centigrade Temperature:%f\n",centigrade);

          break;

      case 2:
      printf("\nEnter the value of Centigrade Temperature:");
      scanf("%f",&b);
      fahrenheit=((9*b)/5)+32;
        printf("Fahrenheit Temperature:%f\n",fahrenheit);

          break;

      default:
      printf("wrong Input");
      }

getch(); //----- ISSUE 3 -----//

return(0);
}
```

Comment: `conio.h` is not a standard C header file, and hence is not located in the default path for system header files.

Comment: `conio.h` and its associated functions, etc. are not standard.  Are you working from a tutorial or example intended for DOS or Windows?

Comment: 1. `conio` is a Windows non-standard C extension. 2. The signature for `main` should be `int main(void)` - old books use obsolete definitions. 3. `getch()` is in the unavailable `conio` mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Issue 1:
Your problem is you're trying to compile code originally written for MS-DOS/Windows terminal on osx. The `conio.h` is a header that provides terminal user interfaces for MS-DOS.

You can fix your problem by replacing it with the `curses` lib

Issue 2:
The signature for main should be `int main(int argc, char** argv)`

Issue 3: Probably related to issue 1, `conio.h` is not available so the declarations for its functions, including `fetch` are not available

Comment: There can be 0, 1, 2 or 3 arguments for `main`, up to the full `int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`. In OP's case, `int main(void)` is appropriate - others could generate compiler warnings about unused arguments.

Comment: Ahhh no wonder! Thank you for the quick replies!

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane the third argument was new to me. D4K please mark as answered if this answer helped you.